# what's the difference between "change" and "migrate" variable type?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, types, migrate

after much googling and only finding some info on migrating I'm still unsure which to choose when presented with what Android prompts me with to fix a type mismatch. I've done both and can't tell if it matters which I choose. Are they in fact the same?

[image]

Comment: In more elaborate code, I think migrate will step through all locations a variable is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Type Migration**

The Type Migration refactoring allows you to automatically change a member type (e.g. from integer to string), and data flow dependent type entries, like method return types, local variables, parameters etc. across the entire project. It also lets automatically convert variable or method return type between arrays and collections. If any conflicts are found IntelliJ IDEA warns you about them.

[REF Link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/type-migration.html)

Comment: thanks.. both answers helped confirm my suspicions, but yours gave me a more complete picture of what happens with migrate

Answer (score 1):

No, they aren't the same.
'Change' will just swap the type of variable.
'Migrate' is 'smarter', and will search trough all usages and try to solve errors that may occur after just changing the type.
[This is a situation when you can use migrate and change. Write this code in android studio and try migrate and change, you will see the difference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR8pt.png)
[This window will be shown if migrating fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhaJQ.png)